# Rails 5 - Sidekiq worker shows job done but nothing happens

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I'm using Sidekiq for delayed jobs with `sidekiq-status` and `sidekiq-ent` gems. I've created a worker which is reponsible to update `minor` status to `false` when user is `adult` and has `minor: true`. This worker should be fired every day at midnight ET. Like below:

```
#initializers/sidekiq.rb
config.periodic do |mgr|
  # every day between midnight 0 5 * * *
  mgr.register("0 5 * * *", MinorWorker)
end

#app/workers/minor_worker.rb
class MinorWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform
    User.adults.where(minor: true).remove_minor_status
  rescue => e
    Rails.logger.error("Unable to update minor field. Exception: #{e.message} : #{e.backtrace.join('\n')}")
  end
end

#models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  scope :adults,          -> { where('date_of_birth <= ?', 18.years.ago) }

  def self.remove_minor_status
    update(minor: false)
  end
end
```

No I want to check this on my local machine - to do so I'm using `gem 'timecop'` to timetravel:

```
#application.rb
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'

#config/environments/development.rb
config.after_initialize do
  t = Time.local(2021, 12, 21, 23, 59, 0)
  Timecop.travel(t)
end
```

After firing up sidekiq by `bundle exec sidekiq` and `bundle exec rails s` I'm waiting a minute and I see that worker shows up:

```
2021-12-21T22:59:00.130Z 25711 TID-ovvzr9828 INFO: Managing 3 periodic jobs
2021-12-21T23:00:00.009Z 25711 TID-ovw69k4ao INFO: Enqueued periodic job SettlementWorker with JID ddab15264f81e0b417e7dd83 for 2021-12-22 00:00:00 +0100
2021-12-21T23:00:00.011Z 25711 TID-ovw69k4ao INFO: Enqueued periodic job MinorWorker with JID 0bcd6b76d6ee4ff9e7850b35 for 2021-12-22 00:00:00 +0100
```

But it didn't do anything, the user's minor status is still set to `minor: true`:

```
2.4.5 :002 > User.last.date_of_birth
 => Mon, 22 Dec 2003
2.4.5 :001 > User.last.minor
 => true
```

Did I miss something?

**EDIT**

I have to add that when I'm trying to call this worker on `rails c` everything works well. I've got even a RSpec test which also passes:

```
RSpec.describe MinorWorker, type: :worker do
  subject(:perform) { described_class.new.perform }

  context 'when User has minor status' do
    let(:user1) { create(:user, minor: true) }

    it 'removes minor status' do
      expect { perform }.to change { user1.reload.minor }.from(true).to(false)
    end

    context 'when user is adult' do
      let(:registrant2) { create(:registrant) }

      it 'not change minor status' do
        expect(registrant2.reload.minor).to eq(false)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is the class method `update` won't work

```
def self.remove_minor_status
  update(minor: false)
end
```

Make use of [#update_all](http://%20https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all)

```
def self.remove_minor_status
  update_all(minor: false)
end
```

Also, I think it's best practice to have some test cases to ensure the working of the methods.

As of now you can try this method from `rails console` and verify if they actually work

```
test "update minor status" do
  user = User.create(date_of_birth: 19.years.ago, minor: true)
  User.adults.where(minor: true).remove_minor_status

  assert_equal user.reload.minor, false
end
```

Comment: That doesn't matter if it is an update or update_all. Worker called in the console works correctly.

Comment: Does this test case pass?

Comment: Ok rails must have made it work recently but it will still do N+1 queries

Comment: You better update using a single database call

Comment: What do you mean recently? I'm using Rails 5 so it's pretty old. Like I wrote before - if I call this worker through `rails c` everything works well with my code. The issue is why sidekiq didn't perform that action even when it shows as done?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to either do `update_all` or `update` each record by itself, like this:

```
User.adults.where(minor: true).update_all(minor: false)
```

or

```
class MinorWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform
    users = User.adults.where(minor: true)
    users.each { |user| user.remove_minor_status }
  rescue => e
    Rails.logger.error("Unable to update minor field. Exception: #{e.message} : #{e.backtrace.join('\n')}")
  end
end
```

You may also want to consider changing `update` to `update!` so it throws an error if failing to be caught by your `rescue` in the job:

```
def self.remove_minor_status
  update!(minor: false)
end
```

Comment: That doesn't matter if it is an `update` or `update_all`. Worker called in the console works correctly.

Comment: Is your `User.adults.where(minor: true)` returning anything?  Might be a bug in the query or data. Also, `update` returns `false` on an error, which wouldn't be caught by your `rescue` if it were erroring.

Comment: It returns array of objects as expected. If I call this worker in rails console everything works properly.

Comment: might need to reload the code or restart sidekiq and add some `puts` in there to double check and see what the sidekiq job is doing. Running it in the console is great, but sometimes there are weird side effects when running in dev. I'd also put some logging statements in your sidekiq job to see when it actually starts and finishes... your logs say the Job was "enqueued"... but that doesn't mean they have run.

Comment: Ok, how to do that? do you have some example or maybe you could write how it should be done?

Comment: Just add `logger.info(...`  or `puts ... `inside the `perform` method at the start and at the end.